# Route is not found in EmberJS although route is specified in router.js

Tags: ember.js, routes

The problem is that the route is not being recognized in emberJS even though it specified in the router.js with the 'correct' format as seen on the emberJS documentation 1.13.0. This is what it looks like as of now:

```
this.route('business', {path: '/business'}, function(){
      this.route('dashboard', {path:'/dashboard/:business_name'})
  });
```

I have a route dashboard under routes/business which shows the following content:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('business');
    }
});
```

Here is the routing code that re-routes to the webpage whether the person has been logged in successfully:

```
 var _this = this;
 var user = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "http://path/to/login", 
                    data: {
                        emailAddress: this.get('model.emailAddress'),
                        password: this.get('model.password')
                    }
                }).then(function(response, request){
                    if(response != null){ 
                        business.set('businessName', response.business.business_name);
                        business.save('no post'); //I override the .save() so it won't do a post request 
                        _this.transitionToRoute('business.dashboard', business);
                    }
                    else{
                        //skip the welcome part
                    }
                });
```

Despite using the previous ways of generating new routes (successfully I might add), I don't know why it's giving me this error:

> Uncaught Error: There is no route named Dashboard

Comment: The code you show looks good, except `{path: '/business'}` should be. You should show some code more. How you got that error?

Comment: hey @Artych, I did the path: '/business'. I've added the transitionToRoute

Comment: I asked around and the ember developer said it may have something to do with the routing and the model is not being passed correctly or something along those lines. I'm an ember noob, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly specified the route name in transitionToRoute() function. For nested routes, the route name will be something like 
{parent_route}.{child_route}.

In your case, the route name for dashboard would be: **business.dashboard**

For more details about nesting, please refer the below:
http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resetting-nested-route-namespace

Hope this helps. Please do try and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: hey - yeah, I tried business.dashboard before but still not working. Another emberJS dev suggested using business/dashboard.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to put your code in ember-twiddle (http://ember-twiddle.com/) or JSBin. Secondly, it looks like there is a mistake in your routing code that re-routes the webpage. AFAIK, the "user" variable will hold a promise rather than a response.

Comment: Hi @phkavitha - I think i fixed what you were referring to, not sure. Although I'm back to square one with this blasted 'Dashboard' error. And this is the github gist: https://gist.github.com/macmania/db44ab49ddd6b3d75f29.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue that I was able to find out when checking your code:

There is no property named as "**business_name**" in the model object "Business".And, you have used the "**business_name**" as the dynamic segment when defining the route.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

- Use a model specific serializer.
- Change the dynamic segment or the attribute in your model.

Please do try it and let me know if it works. Thanks.